# JQuery slideDown doesn't work when first clicked

Tags: jquery

When I use slideDown my box just appears and doesn't slideDown when I first click on the link, but every subsequent click, it works as intended:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Gc6Q/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box.removeClass("hide");` must be after `slideDown` complete demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3Gc6Q/9/ :

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var box = $("#test");

    if (box.hasClass("hide")) {

        box.slideDown(function(){box.removeClass("hide");});
    }
    else {
        box.slideUp(function() {

            box.addClass("hide");

        });

    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `slideToggle()`

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var box = $("#test");

    box.slideToggle('slow');
});​
```

This will drastically simplify what you've got there. It will also allow you to remove some of the unnecessary CSS you've got on on the "test" `div`.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zYAcB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
box.removeClass("hide");
```

The call to `slideDown` will make the div visible. Currently, when you remove the 'hide' class, it will show (since it is being hidden by the css for that class) and the `slideDown` call then does nothing. If you don't remove the class, it will be shown as you want.

Alternatively, you can remove the class when the animation is complete:

```
box.slideDown(function() {
  box.removeClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/3Gc6Q/8/